# Javascript get GMT+0 date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have this code:

```
<script>

    var clientTime = (new Date()).getTime(),
    serverTime = <?php echo(time()); ?> * 1000,
    difference = clientTime - serverTime;

    setInterval(function () {
        var now = new Date();

        now.setTime(now.getTime() - difference);

        $("#pewds_time").text("The current time in the United Kingdom: " + $.format.date(now, "hh:mm:ss a"));
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

This is a "clock" counter. But it shows the time in my timezone.. I would like to get GMT+0, to check what time is in the United Kingdom.

Can someone help me?

Comment: new Date(date.valueOf() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)

Comment: That would be the [**UTC**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// Or:
$date = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');

// This would return the date in the following formats respectively:
$date = '2012-03-06 17:33:07';
// Or
$date = '2012/03/06 17:33:07';

/** 
 * This time is based on the default server time zone.
 * If you want the date in a different time zone,
 * say if you come from Nairobi, Kenya like I do, you can set
 * the time zone to Nairobi as shown below.
 */

date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Nairobi');

// Then call the date functions
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
// Or
$date = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');

// date_default_timezone_set() function is however
// supported by PHP version 5.1.0 or above.
```

**change your time zone**

### [list of time zone](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

javacript method

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```